# data extraction with javascript fetch api

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I am pulling data with fetch api. but I could not retrieve the data in the todosApi section of the last data I pulled. how can i pull data?

```
const usersApi = () =>{
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
    then(response=>response.json()).
    then(girilenVeri).
    catch(e=>console.log(e));
}

const todosApi = (element) =>{
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?userId=${element.id}`).
    then(response=>veriOlusturucu(response.json(), element)).//I can't get the data in response.json
    catch(e=>console.log(e));
}

const girilenVeri = (data) => {
    let cumle = [];
    document.getElementById('arama').addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 8){
            cumle.pop();  
            veriEslestir(data, cumle);
        }
    });
    document.getElementById('arama').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
        cumle.push(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
        veriEslestir(data, cumle);
    });
}

const veriEslestir = (data,cumle) =>{
    veri = cumle.toString().replace(/,/g,"");
    data.forEach(element => {
        if(element.username.toLowerCase() == veri.toLowerCase()){
            todosApi(element);
        }
    });
}

const veriOlusturucu = (todo,element) => {
    console.log(todo);
    console.log(element);
    let html = "";
    html =`
                <h5 class="card-title">İletişim</h5>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Kullanıcı Adı: ${element.username}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">E-Mail: ${element.email}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Web Site: ${element.website}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Şirket: ${element.company.name}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Telefon No: ${element.phone}</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Adres: ${element.address.street} ${element.address.suite} ${element.address.city} ${element.address.zipcode}</li>
                </ul>
                <h5 class="card-title">Yapılacaklar Listesi</h5>
                <ul class="list-group">
    `;

    todo.forEach(element=>{//I need to access the data here with loop
        html+=`
            <li class="list-group-item">Kullanıcı Adı: ${element.title}</li>
        `;
    });

    html +=`</ul>`;
    document.getElementById('veriListele').innerHTML=html;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',usersApi());
```

[image]

How do I return the "response.json" part with a foreach?
There is no problem with user information. but there is a problem with todo information. sends it to me as a promise. I can't access the promise result

[image]

If I can get into the "PromiseResult" the problem will be solved. but i can't reach

Comment: You are missing the step that you do with users - "then(response=>response.json())"

Comment: @maria, there is potentially a bigger issue than just getting `response.json()` to work. Since `todosApi` is asynchronous, there's no guarantee that successive `todosApi()` calls will complete in the right order. And this ripples all the way up to the 'keydown' / 'keypress' handlers; there's no guarantee that the responses to successive events will be in the right order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not quite using the fetch api correctly with the todo list. If you notice, on your userApi method, you include an extra .then which is necessary to return the json data rather than the promise:

```
const usersApi = () =>{
  fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").
  then(response=>response.json()).
  then(girilenVeri).
  catch(e=>console.log(e));
}

 const todosApi = (element) =>{
   fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/?userId=${element.id}`)
   .then(response=>response.json())
   .then(data => veriOlusturucu(data, element))
   catch(e=>console.log(e));
}
```

Try this out.

Comment: `.then(json`. It's no longer JSON at that point.

Comment: @Andy What makes you say that? The initial .then is the response promise. The second .then is the return from that function, which is response.json(). Which is, in fact, a json object.

Comment: `response` is JSON, but then you parse it with `response.json()`. So the information in the next step is a JS structure (array/object etc.), not JSON. There's no such thing as a JSON object.

Comment: @Andy Ahh. Proper semantics. Gotchya. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: Yeah, just call it `then(data => ...` or something.